# UITableView black/crash iOS 8 - No Log

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash, keyboard

I'm building an app for iOS 7+ and I'm testing this on iOS 8 for now.

I'm creating a simple sign up form. Using a `UITableView` where one cell holds a `UITextInput` for the username and another cell underneath holds a `UITextInput` for password.

When I click on the username input field, the keyboard pops up as expected. Now, if I click on the password input field in the other `UITableViewCell` then the whole `UITableView` crashes/appears black. The keyboard remains visible however.

What's strange is that no logs are left either via the Terminal debug output area or the whole iPhone console log.

Additionally - this ONLY happens when running it on an actual iPhone. I cannot replicate the crash/black screen in the simulator (perhaps this is because the keyboard doesn't pop up in the simulator?). I'm using Xcode 6 beta 2 and building for iOS 7 and above. Running on iOS 8.

Lastly - I have stuck a debug output in `prepareForReuse()` for the respective cells. This does not get called.

Any tips on what is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

== Edit ==

After the "crash" the screen appears like (note: the status bar is hidden before the crash):
[image: black post "crash" screen]

Answer (score 0):

Disabling correction fixed the problem - how weird!